# Wedge of homogenous spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $x',x'' \in X$ and $y',y'' \in Y$. Suppose there exists homeomorphisms $\phi_{x'}: X\rightarrow X$, $\phi_{y'}: Y\rightarrow Y$ such that $\phi_{x'}(x')=x''$ and $\phi_{y'}(y')=y''$.

> Show that $(X,x')\vee (Y,y')$ and $(X,x'')\vee (Y,y'')$ are homeomorphic.

I tried the following approach. Call $i_X: X \rightarrow X\sqcup Y $ and $i_Y: Y \rightarrow X\sqcup Y $ the canonical injections into the disjoint product $X\sqcup Y $. By the universal property of disjoint products there exists precisely one continuous map $\phi: X\sqcup Y \rightarrow X\sqcup Y $ such that $\phi \circ i_X=i_X \circ \phi_{x'}$ and $\phi \circ i_Y=i_Y \circ \phi_{y'}$.

In particular this map moves the point $x'$ in the disjoint union to $x''$, and moves $y' $ to $y''$.

Call $\pi': X\sqcup Y\rightarrow (X,x')\vee (Y,y')$ and $\pi'': X\sqcup Y\rightarrow (X,x'')\vee (Y,y'')$ the projections to the quotients. We have that, if $\pi'(p)=\pi'(q)$  then $\pi''\circ \phi (p)=\pi''\circ \phi (q)$, so that, by the universal property of quotient spaces we get a map $f: (X,x')\vee (Y,y') \rightarrow (X,x'')\vee (Y,y'')$ such that $f\circ \pi'=\pi''\circ \phi$.

In particular this map moves the 'contact point' of $X$ and $Y$ in the first wedge spaces into the contact point of $X$ and $Y$ in the second wedge space.

I've built this map only to 'respect the structures', but I couldn't prove whether it is actually a homeomorphism. For sure it is continuous, but how do I see it is bijective with a continuous inverse? My first idea was to do the same construction as above but to obtain a continuous map $g: (X,x'')\vee (Y,y'') \rightarrow (X,x')\vee (Y,y')$, and show it is the inverse of $f$. Do you have any hint?

Comment: What keeps you from constructing $g$? It's the exact same construction, just with $\phi_{x'}^{-1} = \phi_{x''}$ and $\phi_{y'}^{-1} = \phi_{y''}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the map directly. Assume that $\alpha:X\to X$, $\beta:Y\to Y$ are homeomorphism such that $\alpha(x')=x''$ and $\beta(y')=y''$. Define

$$f_{\alpha,\beta}:(X,x')\vee(Y,y')\to(X,x'')\vee(Y,y'')$$
$$f_{\alpha,\beta}(z)=\begin{cases}
\alpha(z) &\text{if }z\in X \\
\beta(z) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Since $X$ and $Y$ both embed into $X\vee Y$ as closed subspaces, then $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ is well defined and continuous by [the pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma).

And it is not hard to see that it is a homeomorphism. Indeed, its inverse is $f_{\alpha^{-1},\beta^{-1}}$ which is again continuous by previous argument.